# Buffalo AirStation High Power N450 Gigabit Wireless Router for a machine shop?

Tags: wifi, buffalo

I'm considering Buffalo AirStation High Power N450 Gigabit Wireless Router as an wifi access point only in a manufacturing machine shop 50 ft x 125 ft area. Good coverage of the area is more important than transfer speed. There are no inside walls, all open area. Would this be able to do the job?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at

[SmallNetBuilder router charts](http://www.smallnetbuilder.com/lanwan/router-charts/view)

I ran across this goldmine a few months back when looking into upgrading my own wifi network. There's a wealth of information to make a more well-informed decision. Once you've plumbed those depths, check out the rest of the SmallNetBuilder site - tons of great information.

The Buffalo hardware doesn't seem to hold up too well against other brands, for the most part.